# error no hay respuesta de la función python

Tags: python, funciones, mongodb

Estoy desarrollando una función que hace una búsqueda en una base de datos, pero para no repetir el mismo código varias veces para los distintos tipos de búsqueda que podrían haber (4) hice lo siguiente:

```
def menu():
    opcion = ""
    while opcion not in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        opcion= int(input(" 1- titulo \n 2- autor \n 3- categoría \n 4- id  \n -5 salir: \n "))
        if opcion == 1:
            query = input("Ingrese el título del libro que desea buscar: \n ")
            tip = "título"

        elif opcion == 2:
            query = input("Ingrese el numero de registro del libro que quiere buscar : \n")
            tip = "registro"

    return (query, tip)
```

donde tip es el tipo de búsqueda que desea hacer el usuario y query es lo que está buscando en cuestión (es un programa de bibliotecas en python), cuando lo mando a llamar
en la siguiente función:

```
def busqueda(query, tip):
    print(f"se va a hacer la búsqueda: {query} {tip}") #Prueba de que recibe los argumentos
    d = lib.find({tip:query})
    if d is None:
        print("Libro no existente en el sistema")
    else:
        for libro in lib.find({tip:query}):
            print(libro)
```

no me da None como respuesta pero tampoco me hace la búsqueda en la base de datos, pero con la línea que tengo comentada se que la función recibe los argumentos ya que el output de esa línea en una de las pruebas que realice fue:

se va a hacer la búsqueda: 2 registro

lo que significa que el usuario quiere buscar el libro cuyo número de registro sea 2.

Hice la prueba programando la función de forma secuencial y si me da el resultado esperado

```
id = 1
tip = 'registro'
d = lib.find({tip: id})
if d is None:
    print("Libro no existente en el sistema")

else:
    for libro in lib.find({tip:id}):
        print(libro)
```

cuya salida es:

{'_id': ObjectId('60adc9a6408965e33f808af3'), 'título': 'Química Cuántica', 'Autor': 'Ira N. Levine', 'Edicion': '6ta', 'Categoría': 'Química', 'registro': 1.0, 'cantidad': 3.0, 'en prestamo': 0.0, 'disponibles': 3.0, 'veces prestado': 0} que es lo que tengo en mi base de datos.

Volviendo a mi código donde tengo el problema, luego de las funciones tengo que se sigan las instrucciones así

```
def main():
(query,tip) = menu()
busqueda(query,tip)
```

el gestor de bases de datos que estoy utilizando es MongoDB pero ese no es el problema ya que en el otro script donde no uso funciones me da la respuesta a como se espera.

Comment: No crees que deberías retornar un número entero en caso se elige la opción 2?  Aparte estas haciendo tu programa muy 8neficiente. Solo haz `if d: return [libro for libro in d]  else: return "no hay libro"`

Comment: ¿Que tal si haces un `print(query);print(tips);`antes de llamar a la funcion `busqueda` para ver que retorna?.

Comment: @DanielBriceño de hecho hice una prueba con eso y me retorna 2 registro que es lo que introduje

Comment: Entonces pasa a la funcion busqueda los dos argumento de  hay ¿que mensage te manda?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Tal como te [comenta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495478/error-no-hay-respuesta-de-la-funci%c3%b3n-python#comment880526_495478) @Christian, el valor de registro capturado en tu código:

```
query = input("Ingrese el numero de registro del libro que quiere buscar : \n")
```

es de tipo `str`, sin embargo, el tipo de valor del campo `registro` en los documentos de tu base de datos es: `number`, tal como se aprecia en el documento de muestra de tu pregunta:

```js
{
  '_id': ObjectId('60adc9a6408965e33f808af3'),
  'título': 'Química Cuántica',
  'Autor': 'Ira N. Levine',
  'Edicion': '6ta',
  'Categoría': 'Química',
  'registro': 1.0,  // <- number (float o real en este caso)
  'cantidad': 3.0,
  'en prestamo': 0.0,
  'disponibles': 3.0,
  'veces prestado': 0
}
```

Otro aspecto a destacar es la inconsistencia semántica de los tipos de datos almacenados en tu documento.

Por lo visto estás almacenando una serie de documentos relacionados con libros, los cuales son (o deberían ser) indivisibles, es decir unitarios.

Aparte de ser un desperdicio de memoria el usar un tipo `float` para indicar las cantidades de libros totales, así como disponibles y en préstamo, es ilógico usar dicho tipo de dato para manejar cantidades enteras. Y es que nunca he entrado en una biblioteca donde pueda prestar una fracción de un libro. Por lo cual, estos campos han de ser manejados como enteros: `int`. Lo mismo aplica para el campo `registro`, que actualmente aparece como `float`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Supongamos que corriges en tu documento el tipo de dato para los campos `"registro"`, `"cantidad"`, `"en prestamo"`(muy mala elección de nombre de campo, al igual que `"veces prestado"`) y `"disponibles"`, de tal forma que todos sean de tipo entero.

Hago la acotación de la mala elección de nombre de campos porque también representan un desperdicio de memoria a la larga. Si bien, puedes tener nombres de campos con espacios (realmente cualquier carácter válido para un nombre de campo en JSON es válido para uno en MongoDB, básicamente cualquier carácter válido par los tipo `String` de Javascript), estás agregando consumo de espacio innecesario en la Base de Datos.

Si cambias el nombre de los campos en cuestión por algo como: `prest` y `score`, (ojo sólo son sugerencias de nombres) que si bien son bastante más cortos y se logra entender a lo que se refieren, te estarías ahorrando 15 bytes de almacenamiento por cada documento de tu colección.

Tal vez en colecciones pequeñas esto no tenga realmente un gran impacto, pero saber esto de antemano te ayudará en proyectos de mayor envergadura, donde 9 o 10 bytes por documento pueden marcar la diferencia.

Con esto en mente, podrías capturar el valor del registro de la siguiente forma:

```
query = int(input("Ingrese el numero de registro del libro que quiere buscar : \n"))
```

Y de esta forma el tipo de dato de la variable `query` será entero, y por lo tanto consistente con el que tienes almacenado en la base de datos (siempre que hayas realizado el cambio sugerido).

Ahora nos vamos a centrar en la lógica asociada a la obtención de los documentos de tu colección.

Actualmente tienes dentro de tu función llamada `busqueda` lo siguiente:

```py
# ...
d = lib.find({tip:query})
if d is None:
    print("Libro no existente en el sistema")
else:
    for libro in lib.find({tip:query}):
        print(libro)
```

Haces una llamada al método [`find()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find) y almacenas el resultado en una variable llamada `d`. Luego preguntas si la variable es de tipo `None` para saber si hay resultados de la búsqueda o no.

Hay tres problemas con esta lógica:

1. El primero es que el método `find()` siempre devuelve un [`Cursor`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/cursor.html#pymongo.cursor.Cursor) o lanza una excepción si alguno de los argumentos recibidos no es válido. Por lo tanto la variable `d` nunca será de tipo `None`.
2. El segundo problema es que estás consultando la colección sin hacer previamente una "pesquisa" para saber si vale la pena realmente solicitar información de la misma. Piensa que no vale la pena realizar la consulta si la misma vendrá vacía. Un Cursor puede estar vacío, es decir, sin datos, por lo cual al recorrerlo no tendrás ningún resultado. De hecho, es lo que está pasando al intentar obtener datos de tipo `str` de campos que han sido almacenados como `float`, simplemente no hay resultados devueltos porque no hay `match` entre entero y flotante.
3. El tercer problema se deriva del primero: no estás capturando una posible excepción en tu consulta. Toda llamada que arroje una excepción deberías manejarla con un bloque `try except`, de esta forma tendrás un poco más de control sobre el posible problema que pueda surgir y podrías evitar que tu aplicación haga `crash`.

¿Cómo hacemos una "pesquisa" y porqué?

Como ya hemos visto, el método `find()` devuelve un `Cursor`, pero para que esto suceda debe realizarse una consulta a tu colección, supongamos que tu colección tiene millones de documentos. Al realizar la consulta usando un filtro, se devolverán todos los documentos que correspondan con dicho filtro, almacenando estos datos, que pueden ser pocos, muchos o ninguno, en un `Cursor`. Para saber si mi `Cursor` tiene elementos que se puedan iterar debo usar métodos propios de un iterable, como `next()` por ejemplo. Sin embargo, como ya he dicho con anterioridad, si un `Cursor` no tiene datos no hay nada que iterar.

Para evitar la iteración y el almacenamiento de un iterable vacío podemos hacer previamente una "pesquisa" usando el método [`count_documents()`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents) que recibe el mismo filtro que usarás en el método `find()`.

Este método te devolverá un entero con la cantidad de documentos que coincidan con el filtro aplicado y podrás tomar tu decisión a partir de dicho resultado.

Por ejemplo:

```py
found = lib.count_documents({tip: query})

if not found:
    print("Sorry, no books")
else:
    # ...
```

Ahora el código es bastante claro en cuanto a lo que estamos haciendo al realizar la consulta. Primero estamos contando cuantos documentos existen en la colección tales que superan el filtro. Si el resultado es 0 (cero), significa que no hay documentos que coincidan con los parámetros de búsqueda y no necesito almacenar ningún `Cursor`.

Ahora veamos cómo hacer la búsqueda usando `try except`, recordemos que esta búsqueda la haremos sólo si la cantidad de documentos que coinciden con el filtro es superior a cero.

```py
import pprint

# si tenemos más de 0 documentos
try:
    books = lib.find({tip: query})
    for book in books:
        pprint.pprint(book)
except TypeError as err:
    print(f"Unexpected {err=}, {type(err)=}")
```

Como puedes observar he usado el módulo [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html?highlight=pprint#module-pprint) para mostrar de forma *bonita* la salida de los datos del `Cursor`.

Esta sería una estructura básica para trabajar con las consultas a MongoDB usando la librería de Python.

El código completo podría verse como se muestra a continuación:

```py
import pprint

def busqueda(query, tip):
    print(f"se va a hacer la búsqueda: {query} {tip}") #Prueba de que recibe los argumentos
    try:
        found = lib.count_documents({tip: query})
        if not found :
            print("Sorry, no books")
        else:
            for libro in lib.find({tip: query}):
                pprint.pprint(libro)
    except TypeError as error:
        print(f"Unexpected Error {error=}, {type(error)=}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unknwon Exception {e=}, {type(e)=}")
```

**Consejos finales**

En el código de tu función `menu()` tienes lo siguiente:

```py
def menu():
    opcion = ""
    while opcion not in [1,2,3,4,5]:
        opcion= int(input(" 1- titulo \n 2- autor \n 3- categoría \n 4- id  \n -5 salir: \n "))
    # ...
```

Si el usuario introduce un valor no numérico, la siguiente linea lanzará una excepción:

```
opcion= int(input(" 1- titulo \n 2- autor \n 3- categoría \n 4- id  \n -5 salir: \n "))
```

ya que estás convirtiendo a entero el valor introducido por el usuario, y como sabemos el usuario puede introducir cualquier valor distinto de uno numérico.

Lo que en tu caso yo haría, es cambiar la lista de opciones válidas para que sean de tipo `str`, ya que al fin y al cabo el método `input` devuelve un `str`.

Tu función `menu()` podría lucir así:

```py
def menu():
    opcion = ""
    while opcion not in ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]:
        opcion= input(" 1- titulo \n 2- autor \n 3- categoría \n 4- id  \n -5 salir: \n ")
        if opcion == "1":
            query = input("Ingrese el título del libro que desea buscar: \n ")
            tip = "título"

        elif opcion == "2":
            try:
                query = int(input("Ingrese el numero de registro del libro que quiere buscar : \n"))
                tip = "registro"
            except TypeError:
                print("El valor introducido no es numérico, intente de nuevo")
                opcion = ""

    return (query, tip)
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.